# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gui' (PySide6)

Tags: python, pyside6

I do not understand why I am getting thins error. The line "from gui.ui.ui_mainwindow" int the following code seems to be referencing the XML file called 'mainwindow.ui' in the same directory. Here is the code snippet where it appears:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon

from gui.ui.ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from gui.cell import Cell
from data.node import Node

import data.algorithms as algs
```

I have confirmed the PySide6, PySide6 Addons, PySide6 Essentials, and Shiboken6 are correctly installed.

I have tried to change the file path within the directory and no success.

I have also confirmed that all file names and their references in the code are correct.

Comment: What is `gui`? A directory? A module? And that `ui`? Where is the `ui_mainwindow.py` file?

Comment: Gui is a sub-directory in the main project folder, and ui is a sub-directory in gui. The mainwindow file is an xml file inside the ui directory.

Cell and Node are being imported from gui with no problem.

Comment: Did you add an empty `__init__.py` file in the `gui` and `ui` folders? Also, I specifically asked about the `ui_mainwindow.py` file, which is the one you're trying to import, if it doesn't exist, you have to create it using the `uic` utility.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you try to reproduce some example without clear understanding what you are doing.

You mentioned the file `mainwindow.ui` that your probably created with Qt Designer or have provided by someone. This file is indeed XML and contains UI elements definitions.
But the line `from gui.ui.ui_mainwindow` refers not to it but to `ui_mainwindow.py` that is expected to be created from ui-file with help of `uic` utility.

But the error `ModuleNotFoundError` is not about it at all. It means that you

1. don't have package with name `gui` installed (that is true as there are no such python package publicly known)

*and*

2. don't have `gui` directory in your project (or if directory is present - it doesn't have `__init__.py` to be recognized as a python module).

So, I would propose you to study what `import` does in python and check what you really want to achieve.